# Using eigen objects in C

Tags: c++, c, eigen

I want to wrap part of Eigen's feature in C, but I am curious how would the automatic storage duration works in such case. For example:

```
/* eigenwrapper.h */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


void* create_matrix(int r, int c);
//and other declarations like addition, multiplication, delete ... ....

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

`

```
/* eigenwrapper.cxx */
#include <eigen headers>
#include "eigenwrapper.h"

extern "C" {

void* create_matrix(int r, int c) {
    return &MatrixXf(r,c);

}

// and other definitions

}
```

`

```
/*main.c*/
#include "eigenwrapper.h"

int main(void) {
    m = create_matrix(3,3);
    /* working with m */
}
```

I assume that Eigen or C++ keep tracks of the number of references of the object, but will that work when I return pointer of object to C functions? Will the object being deconstructed when leaving the `create_matrix` function?

If the automatic storage duration won't work this way, Should I use the `new` keyword for dynamic allocation? e.g. `return new MatrixXf(r,c);` Then how could I obtain dynamically allocated, `new`ed, matrices when I have a function returns `matA * matB`?

Comment: If you want to manage automatic storage in C, you have to explicitly mark when things go in and out of scope. A prominent example of this is the Python C API. If you're writing C code that works with Python datatypes, you have to call `Py_INCREF` whenever a variable comes "into scope" and `Py_DECREF` whenever it "exits scope". It's your job to do that since C won't do it for you.

Comment: `&MatrixXf(r,c)` makes no sense. Use `new` to create an object and get a pointer to it. Once returned to the C code, use the pointer as an [*opaque pointer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) and pass it to all C++ functions that needs it. The C++ function then have to do a `reinterpret_cast<MatrixXf*>(ptr)` to get a proper pointer to the object. And you need an explicit API function to delete the object as well.

Comment: On another note, in C++ all pointers to objects are implicitly convertible to `void*`, you don't need a cast for that. And on that note, whenever you feel the need to do a C-style cast in C++ you should take that as a sign that you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Wrapping a matrix c++ library in C does not make sense. If you really need plain c, find a matrix library with c API like LAPACK. But consider doing your matrix calculations in c++.

Comment: "I assume that Eigen or C++ keep tracks of the number of references of the object" -- No, that does not happen, unless you use something like `std::shared_ptr`. Also taking the address of an rvalue is not legal, I think (I'm not a language lawyer ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, C++ does not keep track of references. If you want a C API, you have to deal with this yourself.

### Opaque pointers

As far as wrapping Eigen functions into C API, I would go with opaque pointers instead of void* so that you have at least some type safety.

Here is a suitable header:

```
#pragma once

#include <stddef.h>
/* using ptrdiff_t */

/** forward-declared opaque handle for matrix */
typedef struct EigenMatrixXf EigenMatrixXf;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

EigenMatrixXf* eigen_matrixxf_create(ptrdiff_t rows, ptrdiff_t cols);
EigenMatrixXf* eigen_matrixxf_add(
      const EigenMatrixXf* left, const EigenMatrixXf* right);
void eigen_matrixxf_free(EigenMatrixXf* self);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} /* extern "C" */
#endif
```

And here the cpp file

```
struct EigenMatrixXf
{
    Eigen::MatrixXf mat;
};
EigenMatrixXf* eigen_matrixxcf_create(ptrdiff_t rows, ptrdiff_t cols)
try {
    return new EigenMatrixXf{ Eigen::MatrixXf(rows, cols) };
} catch(std::bad_alloc&) {
    errno = ENOMEM;
    return nullptr;
}
EigenMatrixXf* eigen_matrixxf_add(
      const EigenMatrixXf* left, const EigenMatrixXf* right)
try {
    return new EigenMatrixXf{ left->mat + right->mat };
} catch(std::bad_alloc&) {
    errno = ENOMEM;
    return nullptr;
}
void eigen_matrixxcf_free(EigenMatrixXf* self)
{ delete self; }
```

If you want to use fixed-size Eigen objects, read up on the allocator issues here: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html

### Mapping C structs

You can also use Eigen's `Map` function give an Eigen *view* to a C struct. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html
There are a few tradeoffs here when it comes to API design and performance (e.g. number of dynamic allocations, alignment, etc.)

Header:

```
#pragma once

#include <stddef.h>
/* using ptrdiff_t */

typedef struct EigenMatrixXf
{
    float* ptr;
    ptrdiff_t rows, cols;
} EigenMatrixXf;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

EigenMatrixXf eigen_matrixxf_create(ptrdiff_t rows, ptrdiff_t cols);
EigenMatrixXf eigen_matrixxf_add(
    const EigenMatrixXf* left, const EigenMatrixXf* right);
void eigen_matrixxf_free(EigenMatrixXf* self);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} /* extern "C" */
#endif
```

Cpp file:

```
inline Eigen::MatrixXf::MapType map(EigenMatrixXf& ctype)
{ return Eigen::MatrixXf::MapType(ctype.ptr, ctype.rows, ctype.cols); };

inline Eigen::MatrixXf::ConstMapType map(const EigenMatrixXf& ctype)
{ return Eigen::MatrixXf::ConstMapType(ctype.ptr, ctype.rows, ctype.cols); };

EigenMatrixXf eigen_matrixxf_create(ptrdiff_t rows, ptrdiff_t cols)
try {
    return EigenMatrixXf { new float[rows * cols], rows, cols };
} catch(std::bad_alloc&) {
    errno = ENOMEM;
    return EigenMatrixXf { nullptr, 0, 0 };
}
EigenMatrixXf eigen_matrixxf_add(
      const EigenMatrixXf* left, const EigenMatrixXf* right)
{
    EigenMatrixXf rtrn = eigen_matrixxf_create(left->rows, left->cols);
    if(! rtrn.ptr)
      return rtrn;
    map(rtrn) = map(*left) + map(*right);
    return rtrn;
}
void eigen_matrixxf_free(EigenMatrixXf* self)
{ delete[] self->ptr; }
```

Comment: Thank you! The mapping method is elegant. I just wonder how much cost will be for mapping `float*` to `MatrixXf`.

Comment: @GabriellaChaos There is practically no cost. The compiler will optimize the object away. Instead of Map you could also use MapAligned if you ensure that your arrays are 16-byte aligned. That technically will make better code for old CPUs but it will also include a runtime check to see if the pointer is really aligned. So IMHO it is not worth it.